# Apache Solr Severe Error

Tags: solr, solr4

Okay, I'm running a single-core Solr setup with Apache Tomcat on webfaction. After some struggles I got Tomcat to recognize Solr, however, when I navigate to the Solr admin, I get this error:

```
Mar 11, 2014 5:04:22 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class      'solr.VelocityResponseWriter'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:425)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:447)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:1556)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:1550)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:1583)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initWriters(SolrCore.java:1466)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:556)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
    ... 29 more
```

I know nothing of Java and have very little experience with Linux, Apache or Tomcat at this level. I've tried searching documentation, but can only find vague references to the `VelocityResponseWriter` needing to be installed.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know what version of Solr you're working on, but it looks like you don't have the Velocity macro language package installed.  I'm guessing that you might be missing some steps in the instructions you're following.  Also, unless you have some reason to use Tomcat, I would strongly suggest you abandon Tomcat and use Jetty.  Setup under Jetty is far easier.

Comment: @AndyLester , thanks. I was using Tomcat because I don't know anything about Solr and the only tutorial for Webfaction I could find was for Tomcat. I am using Solr 4.5. I will try Jetty. Thanks again for the assist.

Comment: I don't know what Webfaction is, but you should probably be looking at the Solr wiki for most of your documentation and tutorial needs. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage

Comment: Yeah, I read through the Solr install on Tomcat. I thought my problems were coming from misconfigured lib directories in solrconfig.xml, but when I pointed everything to the right directory, I still got the error.

Comment: To the question: Your tomcat app is missing some jars... You can also exclude the `VelocityResponseWriter` from the `solrcofig.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Your tomcat app is probably missing these jars:

- `solr-4.5.0/dist/solr-velocity-4.5.0.jar`
- `solr-4.5.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velocity-1.7.jar`
- `solr-4.5.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velocity-tools-2.0.jar`
- `solr-4.5.0/contrib/velocity/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar`
- `solr-4.5.0/contrib/velocity/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar`

You can also exclude the `VelocityResponseWriter` from your `solrcofig.xml`.

Or you can fix jar inclusions in `solrcofig.xml`. Try fix these config lines to find the jar files:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
```